# Why does StackOverflow only link to 'official' sites in the footer?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, footer

I recently learnt about the [Software Quality Assurance and Testing](http://sqa.stackexchange.com) beta site, after seeing it in the footer at [Board and Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions). When trying to recommend it to a friend however, I discovered that it is not included in the footer for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) itself (the only site he uses).

On closer inspection, it seems that the Stack Overflow footer has far fewer sites than the equivalent footer on a beta site.

Is this intentional? What's the motivation? It seems to me that Stack Overflow would be the ideal place to advertise the existence of a software testing site, or for that matter, fledgling beta sites in general.

Comment: Beta sites only link to beta sites and non-beta sites only link to other non-beta sites. (In case you hadn't noticed)

Comment: @David Zaslavsky - Yeah, I realised that. I just don't understand why.

Answer (score 4):

As David said:

> Beta sites only link to beta sites and non-beta sites only link to other non-beta sites.

You have to graduate from beta to earn the privilege of being linked to by every single Stack Overflow page.

Answer (score 0):

Then there would be too many links making it look bad. And Google does penalize you in the search ratings for many links like that.

Comment: Well, in theory all those sites will graduate eventually and they'll all be in the footer, so if this is the reason (and it seems kind of unlikely) it's just delaying the problem